# Highcharts Gauge Tooltip whenever hover the values

Tags: highcharts, gauge

I want tooltip whenever i hover 0 to 900 values.
Any idea you have please share me...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZoQX.png)

```
 Jsfiidle link: http://jsfiddle.net/fwxbfu1u/6/
```

Comment: Do you want to show tooltips for highcharts-radial-axis-labels, yes? By default, there is no such functionality in series type Gauge in Highcharts.

Comment: Here my work file -https://jsfiddle.net/1p7a2r3n/
on hover Green and blue line must show values in tooltip.is there any work around ?